# Swift 3 PreviewView created optional but cannot connect it to original AVCAM class previewView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i am making an app where it has two files CameraVC.swift

```
import UIKit
class CameraVC: CameraViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: PreviewView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    self.previewView = previewView   
}
```

}

another class CameraViewController.swift
[Apple AVCAM class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Swift_AVCam_CameraViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Swift_AVCam_CameraViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_15)

in this class i have changed removed the outlet and now this is the new code

```
private weak var previewView: PreviewView?
```

everywhere in this file i have changed it to previewView? (every call optional)

but this is when i am assigning the CameraVC.swift 
its giving the error "**Assigning a property to itself**"

and the cameraVC.main code is added

if anyone had this problem and solved it pls let me know the solution...i am facing this problem from last 2 days....it will be a great help to me

Comment: `self.previewView = previewView` inside viewDidLoad method makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing itself to itself

If you are not using intersect builder you will need to construct an instance of  PreviewView